# How can I fix my CSS code to move the Left column to the left when the screen is large?

Tags: html, css

I've been having a problem with my reactive website; specifically it will not show the "about-me" and "popular posts" on the top left (next to the main content) when the screen is large. I would like to fix it, if possible. Right now, it shows right next to the footer, which is not what I want.

Here is the HTML and CSS I am working with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-main.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Electrolize&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Begin Header -->
  <header role="banner">
    <h1>Incredible Indie Games</h1>
    <p>Reviews and Reccomendations for the Moderate Indie Gamer</p>
    <!-- Begin Navigation -->
    <nav role="navigation">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="index-copy.html">About</a>
      <a href="#">Reviews</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation -->
  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->
  <!-- Begin Main Content -->
  <main>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="leftcolumn">
        <article class="post">
          <h2> Ori and The Blind Forest: A Soulful and Stunning Action-Platformer </h2>
          <h5>Dec 7, 2017</h5>
          <p>Some text..</p>
          <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="post">
          <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
          <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
          <p>Some text..</p>
          <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
      <section class="post">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
      </section>
      <section class="post">
        <h3>Upcoming Posts</h3>
      </section>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <footer class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is the CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Add a background color with some padding */

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 12px;
  background: black;
}


/* Header*/


/*Blog Title */

header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #91c7b1;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
}


/*navbar/*
/* top navigation bar style */

nav {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* navigation bar links */

nav a {
  color: White;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */


/* Left column */

.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}


/* Right column */

.rightcolumn {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}


/* images work in progress at the moment */


/* Add a post layout for articles */

.post {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the grid system from Bootstarp: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The best option you have is to use `flex` for the container. Using `float` in modern website design is very uncommon, and `float` comes with a *lot* of drawbacks. I've modified your CSS and HTML to reflect a `flex` way of doing things.

You will need to clean it up yourself (padding, flex ratios etc). See below for the changes made to get it working as you need.

See this for more info on flex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

```css
.rightcolumn {
  flex: 5;
}

.leftcolumn {
  flex: 1;
}

main > .row {
    display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  main > .row {
      flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <section class="post">
            <h2>About Me</h2>
            <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
        </section>
        <section class="post">
            <h3>Upcoming Posts</h3>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="rightcolumn">
        <article class="post">
            <h2> Ori and The Blind Forest: A Soulful and Stunning Action-Platformer </h2>
            <h5>Dec 7, 2017</h5>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="post">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
```

As for a side note, if you're doing this for an assignment, I would recommend cleaning up your HTML. The class names don't really reflect their purpose, and the `row` element seems redundant. But all up, looks good.

Comment: I had originally borrowed this code from W3Schools, and as such had not wanted to mess around with it too much. The class name redundancy was done in an attempt to get aria labels, which was not ideal. Thank you so much for your help and advice, it has been greatly appreciated!

Comment: No worries, would appreciate an accepted answer if it has helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Check below code. I used Bootstrap grid system.
you can use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ to get more information

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Add a background color with some padding */

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 12px;
  background: black !important;
}


/* Header*/


/*Blog Title */

header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #91c7b1;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
}


/*navbar/*
/* top navigation bar style */

nav {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* navigation bar links */

nav a {
  color: White;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */


/* Left column */

.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}


/* Right column */

.rightcolumn {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}


/* images work in progress at the moment */


/* Add a post layout for articles */

.post {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-main.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Electrolize&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Begin Header -->
    <header role="banner">
      <h1>Incredible Indie Games</h1>
      <p>Reviews and Reccomendations for the Moderate Indie Gamer</p>
      <!-- Begin Navigation -->
      <nav role="navigation">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="index-copy.html">About</a>
        <a href="#">Reviews</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
      <!-- End Navigation -->
    </header>
    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- Begin Main Content -->
    <main>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <article class="post">
            <h2> Ori and The Blind Forest: A Soulful and Stunning Action-Platformer </h2>
            <h5>Dec 7, 2017</h5>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
          </article>
          <article class="post">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
          </article>
        </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <section class="post">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
        </section>
        <section class="post">
          <h3>Upcoming Posts</h3>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing Bootstrap would be better solution for anykind of design for you.
The following code may become yous solution.

```html
<html><head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-main.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Electrolize&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    /* Add a background color with some padding */

    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      padding: 12px;
      background: black;
    }


    /* Header*/


    /*Blog Title */

    header {
      padding: 10px;
      background: #91c7b1;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
    }


    /*navbar/*
    /* top navigation bar style */

    nav {
      background-color: #000;
      overflow: hidden;
    }


    /* navigation bar links */

    nav a {
      color: White;
      float: left;
      font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }


    /* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */


    /* Left column */

    .leftcolumn {
      float: left;
      width: 75%;
    }


    /* Right column */

    .rightcolumn {
      float: right;
      width: 20%;
    }


    /* images work in progress at the moment */


    /* Add a post layout for articles */

    .post {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }


    /* Clear floats after the columns */

    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }


    /* Footer */

    footer {
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }


    /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .leftcolumn,
      .rightcolumn {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Begin Header -->
  <header role="banner">
    <h1>Incredible Indie Games</h1>
    <p>Reviews and Reccomendations for the Moderate Indie Gamer</p>
    <!-- Begin Navigation -->
    <nav role="navigation">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="index-copy.html">About</a>
      <a href="#">Reviews</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation -->
  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->
  <!-- Begin Main Content -->
  <main>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="leftcolumn">
        <article class="post">
          <h2> Ori and The Blind Forest: A Soulful and Stunning Action-Platformer </h2>
          <h5>Dec 7, 2017</h5>
          <p>Some text..</p>
          <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="post">
          <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
          <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
          <p>Some text..</p>
          <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="rightcolumn">
          <aside>
        <section class="post">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
        </section>
        <section class="post">
          <h3>Upcoming Posts</h3>
        </section>
          </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

    


  <footer class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
  </footer>


</body></html>
```

Comment: For the assignment that we are expected to complete, my professor has said that we are not allowed to use bootstrap. Thank you so much for this though!